# Toggle a progress bar on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

In the plunker below, upon click of the first the popout comes and the progress bar should load with width:90% as shown above. To do that I have added a onClick method which adds a class clicked but it is not working.

I have used the materializecss for popout functionality.

The simple jQuery I used is

```
$('.h_first').on('click', function() {
  $('.some1').toggleClass('clicked');
});
```

The link to Plunker is [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/MqgZZb5SeftjEzkfPF9G?p=preview).

Comment: Worked for me, I checked your plnkr. Please elaborate on `it is not working`.

Comment: Inside the first popout the progress should load upto 90% on click of first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is that the inline style `width: 0%` will always overwrite the stylesheet. This is because `inline > class`.

Therefore set the width in the stylesheet somewhere as the default state for `some1` and then it should work when toggled.

**Also you need to import jquery first for this to work.**

See the Plunker below:

https://plnkr.co/edit/Y8F32jWxtnzr8zzZpmEa?p=preview

The toggle works and the progress bar uses CSS3 animations and keyframes to animate over 4s from 0% to 90%.

Comment: I have added a new plnkr to the answer and it now has animated progress bar.

Answer (score 1):

Put you script loading tags at the bottom of body, and use the !important for your css class selector.

```
.clicked {
  width: 90% !important;
}
```

And for HTML file:

```
<body>
...
<script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
```

The problem is that the script is done running when the document didn't even loaded up and the !important is used to override your already placed value of width:90%. Hope that it helped you.

Comment: one more question how can i add transition of progress bar upon the click can u help me

Comment: I mean on click the progress bar should load from 0 to 90%